# google map shows white patches

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

This just started happening a few days ago.  For some reason, the default google map (Even the one from the samples page: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple) shows white patches on the map for different zoom levels.  In one instance, the entire western side of North America just shows as a white overlay on the map, hiding all of the countries and states.
This can be seen on the example map in the link above by zooming out on the map and navigating to North America.

Here's another place where this can be seen: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-region-us (Zoom out 4 or 5 times to see the white patch on North America)

This is definitely new behavior and wasn't there a few days ago.  Is anyone else experiencing a similar issue with google maps?

Comment: both sites look ok from where i am at (malaysia)

Comment: I'm getting the same problem in chrome and IE... I posted screenshots of what it looks like for me here: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5787